# Validate text file using VB

Tags: validation, text

Could you please advice me on getting the VB script for my below mentioned scenario!!!

Scenario:

VB script needs to open the text file and reads all the lines in the text file but main conditions are for example if the text file named read.000 so the VB script opens the file named read.000 then the validation of the text file should starts with reading the first line of the text file and that first line in the text file is same as the file name read.000 so VB script validation should exactly match first line of file with text file name(read.000). also, the file name can be any read.001 or read.002 whatever the file name it should be same inside the file which present in first line of the file. 
if the condition satisfied then only it needs to go for second validation.
Once file name validation is satisfied then VB script needs to validate the text file structure for example, in the text file read.000 the second line starts "01 John lagoon Canada"
In the above example 01 -> represent serial number which should be only two characters if more than two characters then validation get fail
John -> represents first name which should be only 4 characters if its more than 4 then validation needs to get fail same applicable for lagoon.

Could you please advice me on the above request with VB script.

Answer (score 0):

Well hope that i'm getting your problem right, i'll do something like this:

```
 Dim fso, rfile, line
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set rfile = fso.OpenTextFile(pathtoyourfile, 1)
 Do While rfile.AtEndOfStream <> true
   line = rfile.ReadLine
   if line = fso.GetFileName(pathtoyourfile) then
    do your next Validation or something else'must be speficied
   else
    do something or end 'must be speficied
   End if
 Loop
 rfile.close
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. is this script validate the file structure i mean all the statements in the file should be in specific length (when you do cntrl+A all the statements should be on same lenght). if any statement been in the incorrect format the alert needs to be created in the Event viewer saying the which particular line as incorrect format.

Comment: the posted script is just the snippet for reading a line from a given file. what you need to implement is the validation part. the variable `line` contains one line of from the given file. With that content you should be able to get the `length` of the line or could check it against your specific patterns, to evaluate the nessesity to create/raise an event or not.

Comment: One more query. Am trying this in C#,

Basically please suggest me how to to validate the text file.
The validations should be,
1) How to validate the file name which has to be excatly match with name mentioned inside the file. e.g. text file name 'TEST_DDMMYY.000' this should validate whether name present exactly inside the text file where DD- date, MM-month and YY-year.

2) How to validate the content given in the file are in fixed length. for sample say fixed length is 100.